# Trouble Populating All Fields of a Database

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import a text file into a MySQL database, and I'm having trouble getting the first field (card_no) to populate completely in all of my records. After I import the file (which does not produce any errors), the first record shows up correctly but the other records do not. Can anyone tell me how I can remedy this? -- And in case it matters, I was using phpMyAdmin to load the file. -- Thanks for your time.

Here's the structure of the database:

```
Field       Type            Collation         Attributes    Null    
card_no     smallint(6)                       Yes           NULL
name        varchar(100)    latin1_swedish_ci No    
artist      varchar(30)     latin1_swedish_ci Yes           NULL
color       varchar(25)     latin1_swedish_ci Yes           NULL
rarity      varchar(1)      latin1_swedish_ci Yes           NULL
expansion   varchar(50)     latin1_swedish_ci Yes           NULL
```

Here's the code:

```
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\xampp\\tmp\\php43.tmp'
    INTO TABLE `mtginfo` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
    ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY ',';
```

Here's the imported file:

```
    "1";"Ajani Goldmane";"Aleksi Briclot";"White";"M";"Magic 2010",
    "2";"Angel's Mercy";"Andrew Robinson";"White";"C";"Magic 2010",
    "3";"Armored Ascension";"Jesper Ejsing";"White";"U";"Magic 2010",
    "4";"Baneslayer Angel";"Greg Staples";"White";"M";"Magic 2010",
    "5";"Blinding Mage";"Eric Deschamps";"White";"C";"Magic 2010"
```

Here's a sample of the output:

```
    card_no name            artist          color   rarity  expansion
    1       Ajani Goldmane  Aleksi Briclot  White   M       Magic 2010
    0       Angel's Mercy   Andrew Robinson White   C       Magic 2010
    0       Armored Ascensi Jesper Ejsing   White   U       Magic 2010
    0       Baneslayer Ange Greg Staples    White   M       Magic 2010
    0       Blinding Mage   Eric Deschamps  White   C       Magic 2010
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the protocol is for answering your own question, so in case anyone else has this issue I'll post the solution I just discovered. -- I have the CARD_NO field type as smallint, and I'm trying to load a non-integer type into it. Hence the import does not load the char type (char because of the quotes), and it moves to the next field. -- Thanks again for the answer Devart. While your response didn't correct my issue, it did get me to think about my problem so more.

Answer (score 1):

All new lines are started with some white spaces. You should process them specifying LINES STARTING BY clause, e.g. -

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'd:\\1\\php43.tmp'
INTO TABLE 'C:\\xampp\\tmp\\php43.tmp'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES STARTING BY '        ' TERMINATED BY ',';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Devart. Unfortunately the same result still appears. Wouldn't the LINES STARTING BY be unnecessary since the TERMINATED BY is there?-- I'm just puzzled as to why it won't see any other card_no data but the rest of the fields are populating fine.

Comment: I have added LINES STARTING BY because example contais some whire spaces at the beginning. Maybe MySQL cannot parse it correctly. Try to edit your CSV file, remove all unnecessary whitespaces.